# Array inside array by index not working

Tags: php, arrays

I seem to be unable to access an array inside an array with index.

this

```
var_dump($graphed[0]);
```

give me this

```
array (size=2)
  'date' => string '02-03-15' (length=8)
  'weight' => string '82.327015155' (length=12)
```

this

```
var_dump($graphed[0]['weight']);
```

gives me this

```
 string '82.327015155' (length=12)
```

***BUT*** this

```
var_dump($graphed[0][1]);
```

gives me ***THIS***

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: progress/compare.php

Line Number: 17

null
```

I have no idea where to go from here. Everything I know about PHP tells me this shouldn't be happening.

By the way, this

```
echo phpversion();
```

gives me

```
 5.5.12
```

Am I crazy? What's going on?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be happening? The inside array is an associative array. It has elements indexed by the keys `date` and `weight`. It doesn't have anything at index `1`.

Comment: What do you expect `$graphed[0][1]` to return?

Comment: I expect $graphed[0][1] to return the same as $graphed[0]['weight'] because 1 is the index key to 'weight'. date is index 0, weight is index 1. This is something I've learned and used for nearly a year now, and it's always worked. If I'm overlooking something simple or my understanding of index keys is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Have you been doing it with arrays returned by functions like `mysql_fetch_array()`? This function returns the row with BOTH numeric and named keys. But that's not a general feature of PHP arrays, it's specific to that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP makes a clear destinction between associative elements (with a key) and indexed elements (with an index). You **can't** access an element with a key in such way. In other words: **they are not interleaved**. PHP sees an array as a **composition** of an `Array`(`List`) (like you known them in Java) and a `HashMap`. The difference with Java is that the keys are furthermore guaranteed to be ordered. But that doesn't mean the keys themselve correspond to an index. In a `HashMap<T>` you neither can get the `i`-th value.

**Example**:

```
php > var_dump(array(1,2,3,'foo'=>'bar',7));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3]=>
  int(7)
}
```

In other words, `"foo"` doesn't map on an index, the index numbering only considers indexed elements. For the *indexer*, it's as if `"foo" => "bar"` doesn't exist.

You can however **obtain the list of keys** - which is an indexed array - and then pick that key as is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769148/accessing-an-associative-array-by-integer-index-in-php):

```
$keys = array_keys($graphed[0]);
echo $graphed[0][$keys[1]];
```

[PHP guarantees key ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914730/are-php-associative-arrays-ordered) so it's safe to do so (given you know of course the order in advance, or know what you are doing).

Note that the **keys** include the indices:

```
php > var_dump(array_keys(array(1,2,3,'foo'=>'bar',7)));
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [4]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation and excellent answer. I always appreciate getting both. Will checkmark if I have success with it.

Comment: A note of advice, the comments on java didn't apply to me, perhaps my assumption made it seem so.

Comment: @Goose: well it is only meant in case you don't know how `HashMap`s work and want to look them up, you can find the mechanism in the java documentation. But it is probably not the essential part of the answer ;).