# Get nth key of associative php array

Tags: php, arrays, key, associative-array

I want to get the value of the KEY of an associative PHP array at a specific entry.  Specifically, I know the KEY I need is the key to the second entry in the array.

Example:

```
$array = array('customer' => 'Joe', 'phone' => '555-555-5555');
```

What I'm building is super-dynamic, so I do NOT know the second entry will be 'phone'. Is there an easy way to grab it?

In short, (I know it doesn't work, but...) I'm looking for something functionally equivalent to:  `key($array[1]);`

Comment: That's a very unusual requirement for an **associative** array.

Comment: Question shown as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769148/accessing-an-associative-array-by-integer-index-in-php is not the same.  He's wants to set a value based on index, I'm needing to reference the key value based on index.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)** produces a numerical array of an array's keys.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$key = $keys[1];
```

If you're using PHP 5.4 or above, you can use a short-hand notation:

```
$key = array_keys($array)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks.  Especially for the second line.  Was not aware of this shortcut. It works but unfortunately, my DW CS5.5 error checking doesn't like it.

Comment: Gah, i've been screwing around with reset(array) then key(array), this method is a lot easier. Simple thing overlooked.

Comment: array_keys will generate a full copy of all the keys. Very inefficient on long arrays.

Comment: @FrancescoMM, do you have a very long associative array? that's probably a code smell.  The other alternative is iterating through your array, but if you actually want to reference your associative array by integers, you would need to create a new structure.

Comment: @FrancescoMM  I'm not following you, where did reversing the array come from?  Generally speaking, an associative array is a hash table, it's ideal for indexing but not ordering.  If you have a new problem than the one listed here, feel free to link to your question, but I would recommend making sure you're using the right data structure in the first place.