# Get data of an array without timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

How can I retrieve the data from this array without using the timestamp?

e.g. element 1, element 25, element 45

```
{
    "1620066141": [21.5, 1117, 45, 52, 1010.5],
    "1620067941": [20.399999999999999, 738, 44, 53, 1010.4],
    "1620069741": [20.699999999999999, 961, 45, 54, 1010.2],
    "1620071541": [21.199999999999999, 1131, 45, 53, 1010.1],
[...]
}
```

Like:

```
$data->body->element[1]
$data->body->element[25]
$data->body->element[45]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get nth key of associative php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737606/get-nth-key-of-associative-php-array)

Answer (score 0):

let the old array be `$old` and new is `$new`

```
foreach($old as key => $value){
    $new[] = $value; 
}
```

i think also you want to add it to `$data->body` use:

```
$data->body->element = $new;
```

Comment: This is exactly what [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) does.

Answer (score 0):

Use Foreach loop to access each node's data.

```
foreach($datas as $data) {
     echo $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). However, array_values() only accepts a array. When you have an object, you need to convert it to an array.

```
$json = <<< DATA
{"1620066141": [21.5, 1117, 45, 52, 1010.5],
    "1620067941": [20.399999999999999, 738, 44, 53, 1010.4],
    "1620069741": [20.699999999999999, 961, 45, 54, 1010.2],
    "1620071541": [21.199999999999999, 1131, 45, 53, 1010.1]
}
DATA;
$data = json_decode($json);

$element = array_values((array)$data);

print_r($element[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Object.keys() and map() method in ES6

Here is another possible way using the `Object.keys()` and `map()` method in **ES6** to do it in one line:

```
let element = Object.keys(myObject).map(val => myObject[val]);
```

```js
// let's declare your object {} as variable
const myObject = {
  "1620066141": [21.5, 1117, 45, 52, 1010.5],
  "1620067941": [20.399999999999999, 738, 44, 53, 1010.4],
  "1620069741": [20.699999999999999, 961, 45, 54, 1010.2],
  "1620071541": [21.199999999999999, 1131, 45, 53, 1010.1],
};

// Create an array of strings that represent all the enumerable
// properties of the given object 
// (here: 'timestamps' , which are your keys)
//
// Then:
// Map that array of properties (keys) into their values 
// (here: element[] -- the values without keys)

let element = Object.keys(myObject).map(val => myObject[val]);

console.log(element);

// now you can access your data via index
// element[0], element[1], etc ...

console.log('first element:')
console.log(element[0]);

console.log('third element:')
console.log(element[2]);
```

You can read more about `Object.keys()` method at:

MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

You can read more about `map()` method at:

MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Hope this adds some value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
My solution:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$element = array_values($data);
print_r($element[0][2]);
print_r($element[24][2]);
print_r($element[44][2]);
```