# How to access array in php by index based?

Tags: php

I have a database table for User in that i have two fields USER_ID and USER_DESCRIPTION, If i run the bellow code i get array in the form.

```
Array ( [USER_ID] => 1 [USER_DESCRIPTION] => TAB )
```

But i want to access those value in index based like 0, 1.How to i get that.

```
while (($result = oci_fetch_array($data, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
    echo $result['USER_ID']. ' - ' .$result['USER_DESCRIPTION']; //This works
    echo $result[0]. ' - ' .$result[1]; //This is how i want to access the values
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769148/accessing-an-associative-array-by-integer-index-in-php  Take a look at this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have passed second parameter `OCI_ASSOC` to `oci_fetch_array()` which will fetch only associative array.

If you change that parameter to `OCI_BOTH`, it will return both numeric as well associative array.

`OCI_BOTH` is default. So, even you can put that parameter empty.

Change

```
while (($result = oci_fetch_array($data, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
```

To

```
while (($result = oci_fetch_array($data, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
```

OR To (as `OCI_BOTH` is default):

```
while (($result = oci_fetch_array($data)) != false) {
```

Read it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php

Comment: Hi @krishnamurali, if my answer worked for you, please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this -

```
$result= array_values($result); // Array with indexes you need
```

Or you can do another trick (assuming you are having those indexes dynamically) -

```
$keys = array(
    0 => 'USER_ID',
    1 => 'USER_DESCRIPTION',
);

while (($result = oci_fetch_array($data, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
    echo $result[$keys[0]]. ' - ' .$result[$keys[1]];
}
```

Comment: your answer is awesome and out of the box +1.

Comment: Didn't work with `oci` before so came out with this. :)

Comment: That is quality. You are giving a generic solution without actually working on the technology.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
while (($result = oci_fetch_array($data, OCI_NUM)) != false){}
```