# php class and method from array not able to call

Tags: php

I have an array `$run` that hold `$run[0] - class name` and `$run[1] - class method to run` and i want to be able to do this :

```
// this is working ok
$class = new $run[0]();
// this is error
$class->$run[1]();
```

What is the best and most elegant way of doing this ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769148/accessing-an-associative-array-by-integer-index-in-php

Comment: nope it's different thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `{}` around `$run[1]`: This uses an anonymous class which is available since PHP >= 7.0

```
<?php
$run = [];
$run[0] = new Class {

    public function myMethod(){
        return 'Hello world';   
    }

};
$run[1] = 'myMethod';


$class = new $run[0]();
echo $class->{$run[1]}(); //Returns Hello world
```

Comment: @123onetwothree Yes it will work. The thing that won't work is how I created the anonymous class in `$run[0]`

Comment: and if i have an array with parameters how can i pass that array to the function ? can i use `call_user_func_array()` ?

Comment: @SagarGuhe What do you mean _this might not work in PHP7_ ? The only version in which above code will work is PHP 7.

Comment: @123onetwothree I would use the splat operator.

Comment: splat operator ? how

Comment: @123onetwothree Please google it or ask in a different question. It's out of scope in this question.

Comment: You have an array with parameters you want to pass in the function. That's exactly what the splat operator helps you with. Either describe better what you want or use the splat operator.

Comment: @Daan see here http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php search for this term `Old and new evaluation of indirect expressions`

Comment: @SagarGuhe Okay what exactly do I have to read? Above code works in PHP 7 test it yourself.

Comment: @Daan you found? I have modified my previous comment.

Comment: @SagarGuhe Those are named keys, I'm using numeric keys.

Comment: actually it works like this `call_user_func_array(array($run[0], $run[1]), $params)`